# About the License of GrabCad's shared models

Tags: cad

we were trying to find one **[Dal Mill Storage Shed](https://www.google.com/search?q=site%3Agrabcad.com%20Storage%20Shed%20industrial%20&tbm=isch&ved=2ahUKEwjugP2I-PXwAhX067sIHezBADMQ2-cCegQIABAA&oq=site%3Agrabcad.com%20Storage%20Shed%20industrial%20&gs_lcp=CgNpbWcQA1DLIFjLIGDNJmgAcAB4AIAB4AGIAeABkgEDMi0xmAEAoAEBqgELZ3dzLXdpei1pbWfAAQE&sclient=img&ei=POW1YO7yIfTX7_UP7IODmAM&bih=757&biw=1332&hl=fa#imgrc=ocH4uVfBToNBOM)**, CAD file form the [**grabcad site**](https://grabcad.com).

[image]

If Possible i like to understand can we use the shared cad file of the grabcad site for **commercial usage**.

I have seen [this post](https://grabcad.com/questions/license-for-free-models) about the **grabcad** shared file licence, but I don't understand finally is it secure to use the shared files form grabcad for commercial project. if not, I like to know, **How much change** (percentage) on one cad files is necessary for removing the copyright of one close licence CAD file?

- List item

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Terms are pretty clear on the website: https://grabcad.com/terms

> 6.2.  each user of the Site a worldwide, non-exclusive, royalty-free, fully-paid, perpetual, irrevocable, non-sublicensable, non-assignable,
> and non-transferable license to use, reproduce, copy, modify, adapt,
> arrange, translate, and create derivative works of such User
> Submissions for such user's own benefit and **non-commercial**, internal
> use (the "Cross License")

The license you get from downloading anything from GrabCAD is strictly non-commercial. This includes derivative works - there is no threshold above which you can 'remove the copyright'.

If you wish to use a model for a commercial project, you must contact the original author directly (https://grabcad.com/home/inbox/new?to=zulfiqar.islam-1 for the image highlighted in your post) and agree this with them.